# Hiding a listview group/category in android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'm working on an android application that has a dynamic listview. Items in listView are in 2 types. (group title and items in a group). when I click on a group title view I want to every item in that group go invisible and next group stick to this one.

First: how i relate items to group title? 
Second: how i hide the group items?

Comment: Try to use Expandable Listview.

Comment: You can use either Expandable Listview or add views dynamically to you parent layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark items as hidden in collection, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and in getView() check is item hidden or not, return new View(getActivity()) instead of normal view for your hidden items.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm implementing swipe action for items. I want to reveal a new layout with some buttons. How I achieve this? any idea?

Comment: Put buttons under your list item layout in separated LinearLayout. Your main item content will be placed in upper LinearLayout. Both LinearLayout place in FrameLayout. Add onTouchListener to second LinearLayout. When user swipe, change scrollX on secod LinearLayout.

Comment: I don't understand. Second layout (hidden one) is exactly under first layout or is beside that. Can you please explain more or give a tutorial link?

Comment: Make layout look like this: <FrameLayout><LinearLayout>your buttons</LinearLayout><LinearLayout>your item content</LinearLayout></FrameLayout>  All LinearLayouts are visible!  When user swipe, you must change scrollX of second LinearLayout and first LinearLayout becomes visible.